# Activity or service from a broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I wanted to create an android application that runs in the background and checks for a new sms in the cell phone. I did that with a service that is being called from an activity. That's the code.

**Service**

```
public class SMSChecker extends Service {

    private SMSReceiver mSMSreceiver;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
        mSMSreceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Check Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
    }
}
```

I think that the code is correct for what I want to do.

Inside the Service I'm calling a BroadcastReceiver that gives me the body of the message and the number of the sender. (The code works, but I'm not sure if I'm correct for using the BroadcastReceiver).

Now, I want to learn the location of my cellphone from the GPS_PROVIDER and send it to a cell phone number, but I can't do it from the BroadcastReceiver. Now my question is, what can I do from this point and on? Should I make another service that is being called from the BroadCastReceiver or create another Activity?? The problem is that I don't want a layout for this activity. I want everything to be in the background.

Comment: I think you should call another service to get location and send sms

Comment: Why couldn't you do that? You need to implement `LocationListener` but you can do it in a service as well.

Comment: @StenSoft , 
Because in my code I want to use the "getSystemService" which is available only in Activity and in services I think.

Comment: @ΕμμανουήλΒαρέσης `getSystemService` is a method of `Context` which is the first parameter of `onReceive`

Comment: @StenSoft
When I try to write this code on the onReceive the `getSystemService` is not recognised:
`LocationManager locationManager;
String svcName = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(svcName);
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (provider);`

I have imported all the libraries that are needed.

Comment: @ΕμμανουήλΒαρέσης Use `context.getSystemService`.